# Do we have to retype an abstract method in UML if it does the same work in all of the classes?

Tags: java, uml

Suppose I have an abstract method called calculateRent in my Building class. Then I have two more child classes called Apartment and House that implement the calculateRent method. Both which do the same work in their body. Do I need to retype the calculateRent method in my Apartment and House class or is it accepted to just write the method one time in the parent class and accept that the method will override when we declare inheritance in UML?

Comment: What do you mean by _retype_ in this context? Is it just "write again", since retype can also mean "make it a slightly different type".

Answer (score 0):

You have to retype them ...

But a strange point in your question: "Both which do the same work in their body".

I suppose that you mean that the method in each class compute the rent price but the code is different in each method ..